# i tried to make a Webcam Video Recording to a file using openCV python , i could not open the file with any of my video players here's my code

Tags: python, file, opencv, video, video-player

```
`import cv2
 import numpy as np

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')`
```

even when i use the following formats the video file does not open:'WMV1,'WMV2','MJPG','DIVX','XVID'and 'H264'

```
`rec = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc,17 , (640, 480))
flag = False
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

while 1:
    b, img = cam.read()
    if b:
         cv2.putText(img,"c-Capture  s-Save  q- Quit",(100,50),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
                fontScale=2,color=(100,100,100), thickness=3)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0XFF
    if key == ord('c'):
          flag = True`
```

when pressing c the program starts capturing the video

```
    `if flag:
          cv2.putText(img, "Recording", (50, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, fontScale=2,
                color=(100, 100, 100))
          rec.write(img)

    if key == ord('s'):
          flag = False`
```

with s the video is saved

```
   ` if not flag:
          rec.release()

    if key == ord('q'):
          rec.release()
          break
    cv2.imshow("ViewPort", img)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()`
```

even though all the video players on my laptop does not open the file any help?

Answer (score 0):

In order the main problem is you give False to flag on the beginning. In this case the rec.release() called on start and this will close the empty video file. To solve it you can replace the flag = False with flag = None and then have to fix the 'if not flag:' with something like this: 'elif flag == False:'.
The next thing, I'm sure you don't need the text on the saved video. To do this, you have make a copy from the video frames. One for displaying and one for saving.

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
width = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi' ,fourcc, fps, (int(width),int(height)))
flag = None

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame_out = frame.copy()
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if key == ord('c'):
        flag = True
    
    elif key == ord('s'):
        flag = False

    if ret == True:
        cv2.putText(frame, 'c-Capture  s-Save  q- Quit', (100, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, (100, 100, 100), 3)
    
        if flag == True:
            cv2.putText(frame, 'Recording', (50, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, (100, 100, 100))
            out.write(frame_out)
        
        elif flag == False:
            out.release()
            flag = None

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if key == ord('q'):
            break

    else:
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful